# Is it normal that my LVM mirror log files (mlog_mimage_0/1) are both on the same hard drive?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm, raid, software-raid

I had to setup my root partition with the old LVM mirror capability (as shown below, it says "m" in the attributes). This was required so I can boot on that partition. The new RAID1 doesn't work at all. I tried many times with all sorts of settings but it did not help. Anyway...

I read that it was better to have duplicated logs so I use the necessary command to have a `root_mlog_mimage_0` and `root_mlog_mimage_1`. Great!

Today, I was checking that installation, and I noticed that the disks used for those two log images are both defined as `/dev/sdb5`. In other words, all the logs are on the same drive:

```
  LV                      VG      Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log         Cpy%Sync Convert Devices
  root                    tristan mwi-aom--- <250.00g                                [root_mlog] 100.00           root_mimage_0(0),root_mimage_1(0)
  [root_mimage_0]         tristan iwi-aom--- <250.00g                                                             /dev/sda5(0)
  [root_mimage_1]         tristan iwi-aom--- <250.00g                                                             /dev/sdb5(0)
  [root_mlog]             tristan mwn-aom---    4.00m                                            100.00           root_mlog_mimage_0(0),root_mlog_mimage_1(0)
  [root_mlog_mimage_0]    tristan iwi-aom---    4.00m                                                             /dev/sdb5(472781)
  [root_mlog_mimage_1]    tristan iwi-aom---    4.00m                                                             /dev/sdb5(63999)
```

Is that the expected behavior?

I was thinking that `root_mlog_mimage_0` should be on `/dev/sda5` and `root_mlog_mimage_1` should be on `/dev/sdb5` so if one of the drive fails, the other drive has a copy of the logs.

Is there a way to move the first log image to `/dev/sda5`?

---

The command I used to create the logs:

```
lvconvert -m 1 --mirrorlog mirrored --alloc anywhere /dev/tristan/root
```

Comment: What command did you use to duplicate the logs?

Comment: I updated the question with the command. Could the `--alloc anywhere` be interpreted by the `--mirrorlog mirrored`? I thought that would be for the allocation of the mirror itself.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `--alloc anywhere` permit LVM to allocate the LVs anywhere. You can even have two copies of mirror LV on the same PV. AFAIK LVM in linux want 3 PV for propper, separate setup.

Comment: Okay, I'll revert the `--alloc` and see what happens.

Comment: You may be not able to do this